# What causes an Unexpected HTTP Error within install plugins?

Tags: plugins, 404-error, installation, search

Within "install plugins" I'm receiving an error stating "An Unexpected HTTP Error occurred during the API request." When I do a plugin search it throws me back to my site's 404 page. Any idea what would prevent my site from syncing properly with WordPress's servers?

[image]

I added Hameedullah's code to functions.php and recevied this returned 
`object(WP_Error)#21 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(75) "Could not resolve host: api.wordpress.org; No data record of requested type" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }`

Is this a curl transport issue?

Comment: have you tried enabling debug mode and see if any PHP errors are shown?

Comment: I haven't, are you using a plugin?

Comment: Here is how to [enable debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug)

Comment: Wow, so I used debug and the return was terrifying. I'm not sure even where to begin here. I don't see anything related to the plugin section of the site. http://pastebin.com/vrnk0ER0

Comment: All those errors are notices and and wouldn't cause a HTTP error

Comment: Do you think i should be concerned about Undefined indexs and Deprications?

Comment: Undefined indexes I wouldnt worry about. Although good plugin developers should have any. As for depreciations the only thing you can do about that is if its your code then update your code, if its someone else's code then notify them and try and get them to update their code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to dump the HTTP Api response, will help you figure out the cause of error.

```
function dump_http_api_response($response, $type="", $transport=null ) {
    if ( $type == "response" )
        var_dump ( $response );
}
add_action('http_api_debug', 'dump_http_api_response', 1, 3);
```

Example Output:

```
object(WP_Error)#15 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["http_request_failed"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(41) "Couldn't resolve host 'api.wordpress.org'" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: Thanks Hameedullah, what should I be looking for as a result?

Comment: In case of error 99.9% chances are the $response will be a WP_Error object. I am updating my answer to show the example dump. I have also made minor adjustment to add_action call to include priority and expected number of arguments.

Comment: That worked, I've updated my post with the return.

Comment: This ultimately solved my issue. The problem was Windows had dropped the gateway which was preventing WordPress from accessing anything externally.